# LoadRunner/Performance Center with Bamboo

Tags: bamboo, loadrunner

We would like to use Performance Center/LoadRunner with Bamboo for continuous performance testing. We would like to e.g. run performance tests against nightly builds and get reports to Bamboo. There is no plugin available like for Jenkins, so has anyone done custom solutions for LR/Bamboo combination? Experiences and best practices for this are welcome!

Comment: Jenkins plugin, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HP+Application+Automation+Tools

Comment: There is no plugin available for Bamboo, like there is for Jenkins, I meant...

Comment: There is a rest api available for building any integration you need.   That is the beauty of open source.  If a solution does not exist you can just open up the code and build it yourself.  No need to wait on anyone

Comment: Yes and like Madan commented, there is also REST API in PC 12.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any knowledge about Bamboo, but the latest version of PC has REST API to start load tests and other features. If the Bamboo has the way to consume REST API, you may probably integrate it.

Answer (score 0):

(Just 4 short years later ...)

Microfocus has published a Bamboo (server) plugin that claims to work with Performance Center and LoadRunner (also UFT, btw). It's in the Atlassian Market place, see [App Delivery Management Bamboo CI Plug-in](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1217829/app-delivery-management-bamboo-ci-plugin?hosting=server&tab=overview). Follow the Documentation link there to the [User Guide](https://github.com/MicroFocus/ADM-Bamboo-CI-plugin/wiki/User-Guide#start-of-content).

Cheers,
Larry.